# Statement MESSAGE_HANDLER in python

Tags: python, c++, c, ctypes

I'm on a project to implement biometric integration in Python, I use the ctypes library to accomplish this integration.

I have a problem in receiving the touch event on the biometric reader.

The example in C / C ++ I have, create a message map, linking the function to receive the event of the biometric reader, is this touch event, plug, etc.

Here declares the enumerator to WMUS_FP_NOTIFY:

```
 enum { WMUS_FP_NOTIFY = WM_USER+1 };
```

Here declares the message map:

```
 BEGIN_MSG_MAP(CEnrollmentDlg)
      MESSAGE_HANDLER(WMUS_FP_NOTIFY, OnFpNotify)
 END_MSG_MAP()
```

Here is the declaration of the function that will be executed when the event occurs:

```
 LRESULT OnFpNotify  (UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled);
```

Here is the message passed as a parameter created map

```
 DPFPCreateAcquisition(ePriority, GUID_NULL, DP_SAMPLE_TYPE_IMAGE, m_hWnd, WMUS_FP_NOTIFY, &m_hOperationEnroll)
```

I need to convert this to python, so I can capture the event that is passed by the biometric reader. I've tried several ways, one of them was creating a WINFUNCTYPE, However when I run my code, when touching the biometric reader is not passed any event the touch.